# C++ Input/output with files

Tags: c++, file-io

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()

{
    int a , b , c , d; 
    ifstream myfile;

    myfile.open ("numbers.txt");
    myfile >> a, b, c;
    d = a + b + c;

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("result.txt");
    myfile << d;
    myfile.close();

    return 0
}
```

The `number.txt` file contains 3 numbers `10` , `8` , `9`. I am trying to get the program to read them and sum them up in the results.txt.

The errors I get are:

```
conflicting declaration 'std :: ifstream myfile'
no match for 'operator << in myfile << d'
'myfile' has a previous declaration as 'std :: ifstream myfile'
```

Comment: The error message is obvious You cannot use same variable name `myfile` for both file streams..

Comment: Maybe pick a different name for your `ofstream`?

Comment: You need to read about [the comma operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work).

Answer (score 3):

(This only addresses one of the two errors in your code.)

```
myfile >> a, b, c;
```

This line doesn't read input to all three variables `a`, `b`, and `c`. It only reads input to `a`, then evaluates `b` and discards the value, then evaluates `c` and discards the value.

What you want is:

```
myfile >> a >> b >> c;
```

This will read a value to all three variables from `myfile`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare two different variables with the same name. You are first declaring `myfile` to be of type `std::ifstream` and then later you declare `myfile` to be of type `std::ofstream`. Name your output stream variable differently.

Comment: that cleared 2 errors, thanks, the last error is:


no match for 'operator << in myfile << d'

Comment: You are probably still using the input stream for output. Use the output stream instead.

Comment: @ParanoidParrot Try renaming your variables more descriptively, e.g. `input` for your input file stream, and `output` for your output file stream, so you'll always know which one is which.